# Beginner Question : How to upload and work w/ PHP files on a website?

Tags: php

Since a long time, we have been planning to make a website for our App. Now our App is under-development stage, and we need to make a website for it.

Now, what we want to do is upload a PHP page to our website, and work with it like : 
`xxxxxxx.com/test.php?index=1`.

We have the PHP file/code ready, we just don't know how to get a website, domain, hosting and how to upload a PHP file so we could work like specified above ... It would be a normal site, just like others with some bunch of menus, and a nice design. Our most important requirement is to upload and work with the PHP file :)

Hope you understand our Question - any help is appreciated! :)
Thanks!

Comment: There are usually ftp services provided with hosts services, that's the simpliest

Comment: Thanks for reply @cid! :) Are FTP softwares like file-zilla made for this only? Also, does this require Wordpress or somethig else? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look around for a hosting site, they may have their own solution and will usually give good documentation about how to go about it.  Sometimes the best way to learn is to try it and ask questions when you get stuck.  Although SO is more about programming than site administration.

Comment: This doesn't need Wordpress, that is a CMS and therefore has nothing to do with file transfert. FileZilla is nice for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need a PHP hosting for that. Assuming that you have one. Then you can simple upload the directory containing PHP files to the hosting server using an FTP Client.

I recommend using [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) but you can use whichever you like. Hosting Servers also provide ftp facilities. Check with you hosting provider.

This [dev article by Joeylene Rivera](https://dev.to/jorenrui/6-ways-to-deploy-your-personal-websites--php-mysql-web-apps-for-free-4m3a) gives all step by step details.

Comment: Thanks @pagalprogrammer! :) How could I integrate 'PHP Hosting' for my website? Is there something to do on my Hosting Service? I am using Hostinger (hostinger.com) for my Hosting, and from there only I brought the domain. We just have these two things, not any single thing other than that. Thanks! :)

Comment: @kartik Check this detailed guide for complete reference https://funnelxpert.com/how-to-host-a-website-on-hostinger-tutorial/